# Responsive navigation bar with fixed position when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

When scrolling my list items do not show within the scroll bar. also when I have minimized the screen to a breakpoint the burger icons show and is clickable but when scrolling down the page that has all the links within it (white background page) does not scroll with the page. please compare this website for reference as this is very difficult to explain.. http://findmatthew.com/

I have tried making the position fixed when the break has been met but it still will not show the li tags when this has been done. likewise with the fixed bar when scrolling

```css
.toggle {
  padding-left: 48.5%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}

.nav {
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

ul {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: olive;
}

#containernav.color {
  position: fixed;
  background: yellow;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 65px;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0.2;
  ;
}

#logo {
  transform: translate(-20%, -5%);
  max-width: 5%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-20%, -5%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-20%, -5%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-20%, -5%);
  -o-transform: translate(-20%, -5%);
}

header #logo h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

header a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES */

@media only screen and (max-width: 847px) {
  .toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .active {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="containernav">
    <nav class="nav">
      <div>
        <ion-icon class="menu toggle" name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </div>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="/src/img/logo.jpg.png" width="60" height="60"></a>
    </div>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" download>Resume</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I expect the output when scrolling the taskbar to be sticky.

and when the burger icon has been clicked once the media queries has been met for the li tags to also be shown.

Comment: Your HTML isn't valid and please split the code block for `HTML` and `CSS` for readability. Welcome!

Comment: Btw the html is malformed... the `<div id="containernav">` is closed 4 lines after the `<nav>` element... So the elements in any way won't be displayed correctly

Comment: @LukeSavefrogs thanks I am a new developer how do I fix this?

Comment: @JackJones Just move your closing `</div>` fom line 6 to the line after `</nav>`

Comment: Also move the div element out of the ul element. See: [4.4.6 The ul element's Content Model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried making the position fixed

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .navbar a:hover {
      background: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .main {
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: 30px;
      height: 1500px;
      /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
    <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
    <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time out of your day to do this. I want the li tags to sit on top of a background image and then when scrolling  the background to show in whatever color background. also when the screen his been minimized I want a burger icon to appear which is clickable that will show my li tags.    please look at the website https://glennreyes.com/ for reference in which I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the web pages you referenced and ended up with this. Since you added javascript as one of the tags, I assumed it was ok to add some javascript. I also took the liberty to relocate some element open and close tags to be more correct. Although this may not be the exact result you are looking for, I hope it may help you get further.

The code is in the snippet below:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
            var elementTarget = document.getElementById("frontpage");
            if (window.scrollY > (elementTarget.offsetTop + elementTarget.offsetHeight)) {
                // scrolled past frontpage
                document.getElementById('containernav').classList.add('fixed');
            } else {
                document.getElementById('containernav').classList.remove('fixed');
            }
        });
        function dropdown(e){
            var speed = 1;
            if ( e.classList.contains('open') ) {
                // If menu is open, close it:
                document.getElementById('dropdown').setAttribute("style", "display:none");
                e.classList.remove("open");
            } else {
                // If menu is not open, open it:
                document.getElementById('dropdown').setAttribute("style", "display:block");
                e.classList.add("open");
            }
        }
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.toggle  {
    padding-left: 48.5%;
    width: 100%;
     font-size: 40px;
     color: red;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     display: none;

}
.nav {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

ul {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}
 ul li a {

     text-decoration: none;
     color: olive;
 }


.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
.frontpage {
    background: dodgerblue;
    min-height: 500px;
    height: 100%;
}

#logo {
    transform: translate(-20%, -5%);
    max-width: 5%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-20%, -5%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-20%, -5%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-20%, -5%);
    -o-transform: translate(-20%, -5%);
}

header #logo h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

header a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES */

@media only screen and (max-width: 847px) {
    .toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    #dropdown {
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
    #dropdown.open{
        display: block;
    }
    #dropdown li {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .active {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="containernav">
        <nav class="nav">
           <div>
              <ion-icon class="menu toggle" name="menu" onclick="dropdown(this)"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" width="50px" height="50px" /></ion-icon>
           </div>
       </nav>
       <ul id="dropdown">
           <li id="logo">
               <a href="index.html"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300" width="60" height="60"></a>
           </li>
           <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
           <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
           <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
           <li><a href="#"download>Resume</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
     <div id="frontpage" class="frontpage">

     </div>
</header>
<div class="content">
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
   <h1 style="height:1000px">loooong header</h1>
</div>
```